# How to check category has grandchild?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, category, navigation

How to check category has grand children exist in any of its children using category id?

Comment: the question is bit unclear, please explain it in detail..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO you have the main category id...

```
$categoryId = 9;
//get the category object
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
   ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
   ->load($categoryId);
```

Remember that all categories have a `path` setting where all the category tree from root to the category in question is kept. Something like: `1/2/5/27`.
Now all you need to do is check if there is a category with the path that starts with the path of your main category and is 2 levels down.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addPathsFilter($category->getPath().'/') //this will add a filter 'where path like '$path%''
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//if you want to check if there are enabled grandchildren
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', $category->getLevel() + 2);// search for categories 2 levels down.
```

Now all you have to do is see if there are items in your collection.

```
if ($collection->getSize() > 0) {
    //$category has grand children
}
else{
    //$category does not have grand children
}
```

Comment: If path is `1/2/5/2` its returns grandchildren of as well `1/2/5/27`

Comment: Need to update as  `->addPathsFilter($category->getPath())` as `->addPathsFilter($category->getPath().'/')`

Comment: @ganesh Damn. You are right. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo hasGrandchild(13); // parent Category id

function hasGrandchild($id){
   $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id)->getChildren();
   $catArray = explode(',', $categories);
   $hasChild=false;
   foreach($catArray as $child){
         $_child = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $child );
     if($_child->getChildrenCount()){
        $hasChild=true;
    }
    }
return $hasChild;
}
```